# How can I change the result status in Axios with an adapter?

Tags: node.js, axios, adapter, axios-retry

## The why

We're using the [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) library, which uses this code internally:

`axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {`

Since it only specifies the error callback, the [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) says:

> Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger

Unfortunately we're calling a non-RESTful API that can return 200 with an error code in the body, and we need to retry that.

We've tried adding an Axios interceptor before axios-retry does and changing the result status in this case; that did not trigger the subsequent interceptor error callback though.

What *did* work was specifying a custom adapter. However this is not well-documented and our code does not handle every case.

## The code

```
const axios = require('axios');
const httpAdapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
const settle = require('axios/lib/core/settle');
const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry');

const myAdapter = async function(config) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Delegate to default http adapter
    return httpAdapter(config).then(result => {
      // We would have more logic here in the production code
      if (result.status === 200) result.status = 500;
      settle(resolve, reject, result);
      return result;
    });
  });
}

const axios2 = axios.create({
  adapter: myAdapter
});

function isErr(error) {
  console.log('retry checking response', error.response.status);
  return !error.response || (error.response.status === 500);
}

axiosRetry(axios2, {
  retries: 3,
  retryCondition: isErr
});

// httpstat.us can return various status codes for testing
axios2.get('http://httpstat.us/200')
  .then(result => {
    console.log('Result:', result.data);
  })
  .catch(e => console.error('Service returned', e.message));
```

This works in the error case, printing:

```
retry checking response 500
retry checking response 500
retry checking response 500
retry checking response 500
Service returned Request failed with status code 500
```

It works in the success case too (change the URL to http://httpstat.us/201):

```
Result: { code: 201, description: 'Created' }
```

## The issue

Changing the URL to http://httpstat.us/404, though, results in:

```
(node:19759) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (.../node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (.../node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
```

A `catch` on the `httpAdapter` call will catch that error, but how do we pass that down the chain?

What is the correct way to implement an Axios adapter?

If there is a better way to handle this (short of forking the axios-retry library), that would be an acceptable answer.

## Update

A coworker figured out that doing `.catch(e => reject(e))` (or just `.catch(reject)`) on the `httpAdapter` call appears to handle the issue. However we'd still like to have a canonical example of implementing an Axios adapter that wraps the default http adapter.

Comment: Do you need retry the invocation when api return a code different to 2xx (using axios)?

Comment: @JRichardsz We need to retry in several scenarios. The issue is that the `retryCondition` callback we pass to axios-retry normally won't be called on 200 responses. At this point I'm primarily looking for an example of implementing an Axios adapter that wraps and delegates to the default adapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what worked (in node):

```
const httpAdapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
const settle = require('axios/lib/core/settle');

const customAdapter = config =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    httpAdapter(config).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200)
        // && response.data contains particular error
      {
        // log if desired
        response.status = 503;
      }
      settle(resolve, reject, response);
    }).catch(reject);
  });

// Then do axios.create() and pass { adapter: customAdapter }
// Now set up axios-retry and its retryCondition will be checked
```

Comment: Thanks! This was useful to me, and I would not have been able to come up with it on my own without days of effort.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer valid for Axios v1. They changed internal libs export (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5000#issuecomment-1521957205).

Comment: @Marcin Please feel free to add a new answer or propose an edit if you prefer. I seldom work with Axios anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround with interceptor and custom error

```js
const axios = require("axios").default;
const axiosRetry = require("axios-retry").default;

axios.interceptors.response.use(async (response) => {
  if (response.status == 200) {
    const err = new Error("I want to retry");
    err.config = response.config; // axios-retry using this
    throw err;
  }
  return response;
});

axiosRetry(axios, {
  retries: 1,
  retryCondition: (error) => {
    console.log("retryCondition");
    return false;
  },
});

axios
  .get("https://example.com/")
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message)); // gonna be here anyway as we'll fail due to interceptor logic
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs in a browser environment，you should use axios built-in XHR adapter.

```
import xhrAdapter from 'axios/lib/adapters/xhr';
import settle from 'axios/lib/core/settle';

function customAdapter(config: AxiosRequestConfig): any {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xhrAdapter(config)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
        if (xxx) {
          response.status = 401;
        }
        settle(resolve, reject, response);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think this was in Node, but it was several years ago. Hopefully your answer will be helpful to others.